# Apache Storm not receiving messages from kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am trying to integrate Apache Storm with Kafka. The connection seems to be established fine but not receiving any messages. But the messages seems to have been sent to Kafka servers also while the index file for the respective topic in Kafka server shows some data is present. Is there a way to debug this more on Storm end..? I am using a customer decoder in Storm for the messages. The implementation for Storm is:

```
TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
Broker brokerForPartition0 = new Broker("xxxxx");
GlobalPartitionInformation partitionInfo = new GlobalPartitionInformation();
partitionInfo.addPartition(0, brokerForPartition0);
StaticHosts hosts = new StaticHosts(partitionInfo);
SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, TOPIC, "/"+TOPIC, clientId);
spoutConfig.scheme = new MyLogScheme();
builder.setSpout("spout", new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig));
builder.setBolt("printer", new PrinterBolt());
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setDebug(true);
LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
cluster.submitTopology("test", conf, builder.createTopology());
```

Comment: are you able to consume messages from kafka using the console-cosumer script ? what happens when you run the topology? did you see any errors ?

Comment: I am receiving messages in console-cosumer script. But for this test i used another topic. Since the messages of the topic used in my application have custom decoder.

Comment: When the topology is started is gets conected to kafka without any errors and periodically tries to fetch messages from the queue but receives no messages.

Comment: You need to make sue that the topic is not corrupted and contains valid data .. on the other hand use your kafka sppout to consume messages from the topic yoou've tested with the console consumer script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using your own scheme "MyLogScheme". The issue might be in myLogScheme. Try using the default scheme which is StringScheme. Hopefully that will let you see some messages.

Answer (score 0):

Check the topic name in the main Storm Topology. That both kafka and storm topics are same. Check the brokers in kafka topic

Comment: This answer would be better with a bit more explanation.